# Functions in SAS

Tags: python, sas

I have a function that converts a value in one format to another. It's analogous to converting Fahrenheit to Celsius for example.

Quite simply, the formula is:

```
l = -log(20/x)
```

I am inheriting SAS code from a colleague that has the following hardcoded for a range of values of x:

```
"if x= 'a' then x=l;"
```

which is obviously tedious and limited in scope.

How best could I convert this to a function that could be called in a SAS script?

I previously had it in Python as:

```
def function(x):
    l = -np.log10(20/float(x))
    return l
```

and then would simply call the function.

Thank you for your help - I'm adusting from Python to SAS and trying to figure out how to make the switch.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? The SAS code you posted is incomplete as you cannot run an IF statement that is not part of a larger step, normally a DATA step.  Can you show a complete example? Preferably with example input and expected output. Whether it is even worth the effort to try and make a custom function depends a lot on the complexity of the logic that the function needs to perform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in writing your own functions, as Joe said, `proc fcmp` is one way to do it. This will let you create functions that behave like SAS functions. It's about as analogous to Python functions as you'll get.

It takes a small bit of setup, but it's really nice in that the functions are all saved in a SAS dataset that can be transferred from environment to environment.

The below code creates a function called `f()` that does the same as the Python function.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.log;
    function f(x);
        l = log10(20/x);
        return(l);
    endfunc;
run;

options cmplib=work.funcs;
```

This is doing three things:

1. Creating a function called `f()` that takes one input, `x`
2. Saving the function in a dataset called `work.funcs` that holds all functions
3. Labeling all the functions under the package `log`

Don't worry too much about the label. It's handy if you have many different function packages you want, for example: time, dates, strings, etc. It's helpful for organization, but it is a required label. Most of the time I just do `work.funcs.funcs`.

`options cmplib=work.funcs` says to load the dataset `funcs` which holds all of your functions of interest.

You can test your function below:

```
data test;
    l1  = f(1);
    l2  = f(2);
    l10 = f(10);
run;
```

Output:

```
l1              l2  l10
1.3010299957    1   0.3010299957
```

Also, SAS does have a Python interface. If you're more comfortable programming in Python, [take a look at SASPy](https://sassoftware.github.io/saspy/) to get all the benefits of both SAS and Python.

Comment: I would like to heavily discourage anyone from _actually_ doing this - `proc fcmp` functions are _very_ inefficient compared to straight SAS code outside of very narrow use cases where they're either the only way to do something or (extremely rarely) actually efficient.  I mentioned it as something that exists, but I'd never recommend someone use it.  Macros are the SASsy way to do what is required here, and the more efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way you'd do this is in a SAS Macro.

```
    %macro func(x);
      -log10(20/&x)
    %mend func;

data whatever;
  set yourdataset;
  l = %func(x);
run;
```

You can also of course just directly use it in code if it's trivial like this.

```
data whatever;
  set yourdataset;
  l = -log10(20/x);
run;
```

There are actual functions in SAS, but they're not really used very commonly.  `FCMP` is the procedure where you construct those.  Unfortunately, they're less efficient than macros or directly writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your IF/THEN statements typically I would recommend a Format/Informat for SAS. Your code as shown isn't likely to work as you're also converting types (Character to Numeric).

```
*maps old values to new values;
*can be created from a data set as well;
proc format;
invalue myXfmt
'a' = 1
'b' = 2
'c' = 3;

*create sample data;
data have;
input x $;
cards;
a
b
c
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
*does the conversion;
x1= input(x, myxfmt.);
run;

*display for output;
proc print data=want;
run;
```

For more information I recommend [this paper.](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi30/001-30.pdf)